# Spivak's Calculus, Ch 2., Problem 21: Proving Schwarz Inequality using Specific Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

This question is about a problem in Spivak's Calculus (Ch. 2, Problem 21) that asks us to prove the *Schwarz inequality* in $n$ dimensions using a proof that mirrors a specific proof of the Schwarz inequality for two dimensions that appeared in a previous problem (Ch. 1, problem 19).

First I will show the previous problem, and then my attempt at a proof for Problem 21. My question is if this attempt is correct. It differs from the solution manual solution.

> 1-19 (c) Prove the Schwarz inequality by first proving that
> $(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2+(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2$
>
> **Proof**
>
> $$(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)=x_1^2y_1^2+x_1^2y_2^2+x_2^2y_1^2+x^2_2y_2^2$$ $$=(x_1^2y_1^2+2x_1x_2y_1y_2+x_2^2y_2^2)+(x_1y_2^2-2x_1x_2y_1y_2+x_2^2y_1^2)$$
> $$=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2+(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2 \geq (x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2$$
>
> Therefore, we have shown that
>
> $$(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2 \leq (x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)$$ Take the square
> root  $$\implies x_1y_1+x_2y_2 \leq
>  \sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2)}$$

Here is my attempt at a proof of a more general result, based on the proof above.

> 2-21. The Schwarz inequality (Problem 1-19) actually has a more general form
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n
>  y_i^2}$$
>
> Give a proof of this, analogous to the proof in Problem 1-19.
>
> **Proof**
>
> $$\sum_{i=i}^n x_i^2 \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n
>  x_i^2y_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n x_i^2 y_j^2\tag{1}$$
>
> Add and subtract $2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i \neq j} x_iy_ix_jy_j$ to the
> right-hand expression
>
> $$\left [ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2y_i^2+ 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i \neq j}
>  x_iy_ix_jy_j \right ]+ \left [\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i\neq j}^n x_i^2
>  y_j^2-2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{i \neq j} x_iy_ix_jy_j \right ]\tag{2}$$
>
> Consider the expression in brackets on the right hand side.
>
> For any $i$ and $j$ in the two sums, we have
>
> $$x_i^2y_j^2+x_j^2y_i^2-2x_iy_jx_jy_i=(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2 \geq 0$$
>
> The expression in the brackets on the left hand side equals $\left
>  (\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right )^2$.
>
> Therefore, $(2)$ becomes
>
> $$\left (\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right )^2 + \text{ positive terms }$$
>
> Together with $(1)$ we have
>
> $$\sum_{i=i}^n x_i^2 \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=\left (\sum_{i=1}^n
>  x_iy_i\right )^2 + \text{ positive terms } \geq \left (\sum_{i=1}^n
>  x_iy_i\right )^2$$

Is this proof correct?